# Open CV in Windows 10

Tags: opencv, mingw

How do we install OpenCv in Windows 10?
I have downloaded MINGW 64-bit, and CMake but whenever I use Make, I am not able to generate the install folder that contains all the source files for OpenCV. I have used MINGW with both Codeblocks and Eclipse but to no avail.

Comment: In Windows you can use OpenCV with Visual Studio 2015 just by [downloading](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.2.0/opencv-3.2.0-vc14.exe/download) and installing it with a few clicks

Comment: [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) is the latest version of OpenCV 3.2 Installation webpage. It covers installation by 1) using the pre-built libraries and 2) making your own libraries from sources file. The [pre-built](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.2.0/) version support Python 2.7 and 64-bit Windows compiled by VC14, i.e.VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

## I just got OpenCV working with MinGW on Win 10.

I followed these steps [Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html).

Prerequisites for a basic build:

1. [MinGW](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) C++ compiler
2. CMake

Note: [Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) lists steps for an extended build taking advantage of Python and Numpy libraries (to build the Python interface of OpenCV), Intel TBB (for multi-threading support), Qt framework (for a fancier and more useful GUI), CUDA Toolkit (for GPU computing), Doxygen etc. For a basic build these are not necessary and will be skipped during the makefile generation process using cmake as explained below.

CMake Steps:

A. Extract your version of opencv to `C:\path\to\your\opencv`

B. Create build directory `C:\path\to\your\opencv\gnu_build`

C. Configure cmake to generate the makefile as follows:

1. Launch `cmake-gui` and set the build directory to `C:/path/to/your/opencv/gnu_build` and source directory to `C:/path/to/your/opencv/sources`. Check `Grouped` option and `Configure` using `MinGW Makefiles`
2. Disable WITH_EIGEN if Eigen is not available otherwise set `EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/path/to/your/eigen-dir`
3. Disable BUILD flags for python bindings and python tests (if python is not installed)
4. Disable WITH_LAPACK and WITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS (if OpenBLAS is not installed)
5. Disable WITH_VTK (if VTK is not installed)
6. Enable WITH_OPENMP (the [MinGW](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) compiler provides OpenMP support)
7. Enable ENABLE_SOLUTION_FOLDERS, BUILD_EXAMPLES, BUILD_opencv_world.
8. When done configuring, press `Generate` to generate the makefile
9. cd to `C:\path\to\your\opencv` and do `make`
10. cd to `C:\path\to\your\opencv` and do `make install` to collect the header and the binary files into a separate directory `C:\path\to\your\opencv\install`

Note: steps 2-5 can differ for your own case.

D. Create environement variable `OPENCV_DIR=C:\path\to\your\opencv\gnu_build\install\x64\mingw`. Append `%OPENCV_DIR%\bin` to `PATH` environement variable.

After successful make, OpenCV is ready for use. To use OpenCV with Eclipse follow these steps:

1. Start Eclipse and create a new `C++ Managed Build` project
2. Select `Empty Project`, `MinGW GCC` toolchain and select location as your project dir (i.e. where source files exists)
3. In Project->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Includes add Include path `C:\path\to\your\opencv\gnu_build\install\include`
4. In Project->Settings->MinGW C++ Linker->Libraries add Library search path `C:\path\to\your\opencv\gnu_build\install\include` and Library name to link to `opencv_world420` (the lib name will depend on your version of OpenCV)
5. Build project

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Windows Installation Guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) (or [OpenCV 3.0 version of this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) which is not much different). It is applicable to Windows 10. You don't have to build the OpenCV library from the source files, just download ready-to-use binaries.